# Get public fields?

Tags: c#, reflection

I've got a struct defined like this

```
private struct Combinators
{
    public const char DirectChild = '>';
    public const char NextAdjacent = '+';
    public const char NextSiblings = '~';
    public const char Descendant = ' ';
}
```

I want to use reflection to get a list of all the values of the `public const char` fields in the struct (as specific as possible). How can I do that?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
var fieldValues = typeof(Combinators)
    .GetFields()
    .Where(x => x.FieldType == typeof(char) && x.IsLiteral)
    .ToDictionary(x => x.Name, x => (char)x.GetValue(null));
```

Returns a `Dictionary<string, char>` where the key is the field name, and the value is the field value (as a character).

**Update**: Added where clause based on comments and @nasufara's suggestion, and added `IsLiteral` check based on @Jeff M's.

Comment: Surely you don't mean to pass in `null`? Or is that allowed because their const? You can do better by using `GetFields(BindingFlags.Public)` no? Can you limit it to `char` fields too?

Comment: @Mark, `BindingFlags.Public` is the default, so you don't need to pass it.  And you always pass in null for `const` or `static` fields (since the argument refers to an *instance* of which there is none).

Comment: Inserting a `.Where(x => x.FieldType == typeof(char))` between `.GetFields()` and `.ToDictionary(...)` should limit it to chars.

Comment: He wanted constants only too so you'll need to add `x.IsLiteral` to the filter.

Answer (score 0):

```
private class TypedEnum<T> : IEnumerable<T>
{
    public IEnumerator<T> GetEnumerator()
    {
        return GetType().GetFields().Select(f => f.GetValue(null)).OfType<T>().GetEnumerator();
    }

    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    {
        return GetEnumerator();
    }
}

private class Combinators : TypedEnum<char>
{
    public const char DirectChild = '>';
    public const char NextAdjacent = '+';
    public const char NextSiblings = '~';
    public const char Descendant = ' ';
}
```

**Edit:** Blah... there's no way to make a static IEnumerable is there?